# html attributes coming as encoded values from Database instead of same values Ex; " as &quot;

Tags: html, jsf, encoding

We have a set of links, whose href and anchor text is coming from Database. 
anchor text.

Requirement is  to add the tooltip for one of the links with title attribute. 
So,  I am trying to add title attribute by making changes href_value in DB as
**href_value" title="title**
So that my first double quotes in DB will pair up with starting double quotes of href in code and my second double quotes with closing double quotes of href in code

```
<a href="*href_value" title="title_value"
```

But the browser is considering the whole entry as href_value neglecting the internal double quotes coming from Database.

JSF output link is used for list of links.

Whatever coming from Database, It is coming as enquoted ones.

```
<span> as &lt;span;&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) library for this purposes:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
```

Encode:

```
System.out.println( StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4( "<to_encode>" ) );
```

Decode:

```
System.out.println( StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4( "&lt;to_decode&gt;" ) );
```

Comment: If it worked to you, please accept an vote it up, please